# How to extract GPX file from iPhone mp4 or Mov file

Tags: ios, dictionary, gps, exiftool

I try to extract GPS metadata using exiftool
$ exiftool input.mov (attached)
Which able to display GPS data.
However when try to run with some app (eg:from http://www.registratorviewer.com) the GPS data is not display.

Perhap there is another way. I would like to ask:

1. if one would know how to extract GPS data (if need) in order to
2. display location on the map while play that movie

Here the metada:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.85
File Name                       : input.mov
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 391 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:02:17 21:19:42+07:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:02:19 17:23:53+07:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:02:19 17:23:25+07:00
File Permissions                : rwxrwxrwx
File Type                       : MOV
MIME Type                       : video/quicktime
Major Brand                     : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
Minor Version                   : 0.0.0
Compatible Brands               : qt
Movie Data Size                 : 409646393
Movie Data Offset               : 36
Movie Header Version            : 0
Create Date                     : 2015:02:17 14:19:43
Modify Date                     : 2015:02:17 14:23:00
Time Scale                      : 600
Duration                        : 0:03:17
Preferred Rate                  : 1
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
Preview Time                    : 0 s
Preview Duration                : 0 s
Poster Time                     : 0 s
Selection Time                  : 0 s
Selection Duration              : 0 s
Current Time                    : 0 s
Next Track ID                   : 3
Track Header Version            : 0
Track Create Date               : 2015:02:17 14:19:43
Track Modify Date               : 2015:02:17 14:23:00
Track ID                        : 1
Track Duration                  : 0:03:17
Track Layer                     : 0
Track Volume                    : 0.00%
Image Width                     : 1920
Image Height                    : 1080
Clean Aperture Dimensions       : 1920x1080
Production Aperture Dimensions  : 1920x1080
Encoded Pixels Dimensions       : 1920x1080
Graphics Mode                   : ditherCopy
Op Color                        : 32768 32768 32768
Compressor ID                   : avc1
Source Image Width              : 1920
Source Image Height             : 1080
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Compressor Name                 : H.264
Bit Depth                       : 24
Video Frame Rate                : 25.5
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
Media Header Version            : 0
Media Create Date               : 2015:02:17 14:19:43
Media Modify Date               : 2015:02:17 14:23:00
Media Time Scale                : 44100
Media Duration                  : 0:03:17
Media Language Code             : und
Balance                         : 0
Handler Class                   : Data Handler
Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
Handler Description             : Core Media Data Handler
Audio Format                    : mp4a
Audio Channels                  : 1
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
Audio Sample Rate               : 44100
Purchase File Format            : mp4a
Handler Type                    : Metadata Tags
Make (tha-TH)                   : Apple
Creation Date (tha-TH)          : 2015:02:17 21:19:43+07:00
GPS Coordinates (tha-TH)        : 5 deg 46' 19.20" N, 101 deg 4' 19.92" E, 287 m Above Sea Level
Software (tha-TH)               : 8.1.3
Model (tha-TH)                  : iPhone 5
Make (tha)                      : Apple
Software Version (tha)          : 8.1.3
Content Create Date (tha)       : 2015:02:17 21:19:43+07:00
GPS Coordinates (tha)           : 5 deg 46' 19.20" N, 101 deg 4' 19.92" E, 287 m Above Sea Level
Model (tha)                     : iPhone 5
Make                            : Apple
Creation Date                   : 2015:02:17 21:19:43+07:00
GPS Coordinates                 : 5 deg 46' 19.20" N, 101 deg 4' 19.92" E, 287 m Above Sea Level
Software                        : 8.1.3
Model                           : iPhone 5
Software Version                : 8.1.3
Content Create Date             : 2015:02:17 21:19:43+07:00
Avg Bitrate                     : 16.6 Mbps
GPS Altitude                    : 287 m
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 5 deg 46' 19.20" N
GPS Longitude                   : 101 deg 4' 19.92" E
GPS Position                    : 5 deg 46' 19.20" N, 101 deg 4' 19.92" E
Image Size                      : 1920x1080
Megapixels                      : 2.1
Rotation                        : 90
```